# Using getItem with primary and sort keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

So i have a dynamodb table called tableX with the fields:

```
random_fld1, random_fld2, primary_key1, and sort_key1
all fields are Strings.
```

What would be a getItem example with those keys and fields. I haven't been able to get the Keys: portion working with getItem.

Answer (score 8):

You can use DynamoDB's DocumentClient [get()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property) as:

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

var params = {
  TableName: 'tableX',
  Key: {
    'primary_key1': 'PARTITION_KEY_VALUE',
    'sort_key1': 'SORT_KEY_VALUE'
  }
};

docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else     console.log(data);
});
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html).

Comment: What would the sort value be? If you want to sort by timestamp descending, you wouldn't know what the last timestamp value is...

Comment: @Tom `getItem()` might not be your best choice in this case since you don't know the composite primary key (partition key + sort key). You could use `query()` or a global secondary index.

Comment: btw you instantiate `docClient` but then try and use `documentClient`.

Comment: @wuliwong: You're right. Thanks for the feedback. I've just edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the get item code for above table structure.

The below code uses local Dynamodb table.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var creds = new AWS.Credentials('akid', 'secret', 'session');

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
  credentials: creds
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var table = "tablex";

var params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key:{
        "primary_key1": "p1",
        "sort_key1": "s1"
    },

};

docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));        
    }
});
```